# Is there a way to remove the date picker calendar in both Android and iOS webview?

Tags: html, css, webview, uiwebview, android-webview

Unfortunately the

```
    -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none; 
   }
```

does not work and there is still a tiny arrow in webviews.

Comment: It's been way too long since I messed with Android, but maybe make its color equal to the background color? Oh, just saw a Codepen example, add `::` to `-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` [input date calendar-picker-indicator change](https://codepen.io/hsnali/pen/PQbXmY)

Comment: Thank you! I would like to disable it completely, so that it won't take up space in the view.

Comment: Been reading around: apparently there is no avoiding brute force JS or using an alternative calendar widget with the required capability. Older SO solutions don't seem to work anymore. E.g. in Firefox the code is hidden in shadow root. Silly, a simple *en/disable calendar attribute* would solve the entire (worldwide) issue...

Comment: Have you tried `appearance: none`?